# Retrieving a value from a Listview menu item that has two separate TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Listview that originally listed items from a menu item with one single TextView. The code I used to retrieve the item selected is

```
  menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id)  
  {  
                TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;  
                String strText = textView.getText().toString();  

  });
```

I've now added another TextView so that I have two values for each item one under the other and my menu_item.xml looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
   android:orientation="horizontal"  
   android:padding="10sp">  
   <TextView  
      android:id="@+id/rowid"  
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
      android:textColor="@color/exhibitor_header" />   
   <TextView  
      android:id="@+id/rowidtwo"  
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
      android:textColor="@color/listview_background"  
      android:layout_below="@+id/rowid"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I retrieve the value for rowid when the item is selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then instead of casting the whole view, find inside that view the correct `TextView` object. You can reference it by using the `findViewById` method and the `TextView`'s id:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.rowid);
String strText = textView.getText().toString();

TextView textView2 = (TextView) itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.rowidtwo);
String strText2 = textView2.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use custom view and custom adapter to have 2 textviews in the list view items and bundle those 2 text views in a LinearLayout.

Now when the `onClick` called, just cast it in linearlayout and on basis of that by using findviewbyid you can have the access to both of the text views.